# Webpack alias pointing to a parent directory which dosn't have webpack configured

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a project which doesn't include webpack in the root direct, it's installed in my `website` folder within root directory.

```
project
-> src
   -> App.js
   -> Hello.js
   -> index.js
-> website
   -> webpack.config.js
   -> index.js
   -> package.json
```

and in my `webpack.config.js` file I added a alias entry to point to my components folder:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@my-app/components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

The problem is: When I try to import my component like this `import { Hello } from '@my-app/components';` and I try to `npm run build`, I get this error message:

```
ERROR in ../src/Hello.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/.../my-new-proj/src/Hello.js: Unexpected token (4:2)
```

I'm not sure if this problem is caused just because I'm pointing my components alias in a parent directory which doesn't have its own webpack config or it's something else.

I pushed my code to github so you can see the complete folder structure: https://github.com/osnysantos/my-new-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with webpack alias. If you follow the the emitted error, you will see that babel-loader does not recognize the JSX. I see you have added react-presets to your babelrc file, however those seem to be overwritten by your webpack config. Either remove the preset array from the webpack config, or add react preset to them.